# Предотвращение утери данных с помощью Alert

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть такая секция в приложении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите тут поля для редактирования билета. Здесь есть такая кнопочка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если пользователь не нажмёт на эту кнопку, то данные не сохранятся. Чтобы это предотвратить, я сделал "напоминалку", которую можно встретить на сайтах. `Alert` -  грубо говоря. Она должна дать пользователю выбор: либо *сохранить* данные, либо *потерять* их.

Не думаю, что есть разница как она реализована - поэтому я не буду засорять вопрос "лишним" кодом.

**Вопрос**

Как правильно, при факторе не сохранения данных (в данном случае просто потеря фокуса 
у всей этой секции), сделать эту "напоминалку" видимой (что-то вроде `Visible = Visible` - то есть просто изменить его свойство `Visible`)?

---

## Моя идея по решению (хочу узнать правильно я думаю или нет)

Можно всю эту секцию с редактированием данных выделить в отдельный `UserControl`. В нём определить событие, которое будет вызываться, если данные могут быть утеряны. И обработчику этого события менять `Alert.Visibile`.

Comment: А почему просто не повесить на событие закрытия окна редактированя билета отображение вашего Alert?

Comment: @Bulson, потому что я говорю о секции, а не о целом окне. Я просто не стал скринить другую часть окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свою xaml разметку вы не показали. Значит без конкретики, чисто умозрительно.

1. Вам нужно создать булевый флаг `hasChangedExaminationCard` в котором фиксировать было или нет изменение данных по билету.
2. У контролов есть события `GotFocus` и `LostFocus`. В частности нас интересуют контейнеры типа `Grid` и `StackPanel`, или какие вы там у себя используете? Ну, вот с помощью этих событий и флага изменения данных по билету, можно реализовать алгоритм показа или не показа вашего `Alert`.

Answer (score 0):

В WPF есть такое свойство для объектов Visible.Collapsed он как бы прячет объект не резервируя под него место(память).

Comment: Я спросил о том, как правильно изменить видимость  Alert, в зависимости от того, фокус ушёл с секции редактирования или нет, а не о том как скрыть этот Alert.

Comment: Alert что за объект?

Comment: я же написал, что это "напоминалка"